# npm install react-masonry-css Error Problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npm-install

```text
PS E:\Share me\shareme_frontend\my-project> npm install react-masonry-css
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-google-login@5.2.2
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!     @testing-library/react@"^13.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!     peer react-dom@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!       @testing-library/react@"^13.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer react-dom@"^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from react-loader-spinner@5.3.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-loader-spinner
npm ERR!       react-loader-spinner@"^5.3.4" from the root project
npm ERR!     3 more (react-router-dom, styled-components, the root project)
npm ERR!   7 more (react-icons, react-loader-spinner, react-router, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16 || ^17" from react-google-login@5.2.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-google-login
npm ERR!   react-google-login@"^5.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16 || ^17" from react-google-login@5.2.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-google-login
npm ERR!     react-google-login@"^5.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\pankaj kumar\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\pankaj kumar\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-01T08_45_55_070Z-debug-0.log
```

```
npm install react-masonry-css
```

but showing upper error, hoe i can solve it

```
npm install react-masonry-css --force
npm install react-masonry-css --legacy-peer-deps
```

both are already tried

Comment: Welcome to SO, Pankay! I've formatted your output to be easily read. Looks like you have a conflict there, some dependencies want React 16 or 17 but you're using 18.

Comment: Yes, exactly facing this problem. thanks for your help to formatting my question

Comment: Can you downgrade to React 17 and try again?

Comment: How I can? please explain that things. i am a new student of react .

Comment: `npm remove react` & `npm install react@17` would do.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, following trick helped to get the project working.

Step-1: Close your project

Step-2: Remove `.cache` folder from your project directory. It is located at **your_project_folder/node_modules/**

Step-3: Open your project. I am using Visual Studio Code.

Step-4: Goto your VS Code **terminal** and **execute** command `yarn install` to install new packages.

Step-5: **Run your project** or execute `yarn start` command in terminal.